# zariski closure in $\mathbb{A}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field (possibly not algebraic closed, even possible finite). Let $$ U=\{(a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in\mathbb{A}^n_k\mid a_1\neq0\} $$ be a Zariski open set.

Is it true for any Zariski close set $C\subseteq\mathbb{A}^n_k$, the closure of $C\cap U$ is $C$ in $\mathbb{A}^n_k$? Here $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ is the set of $n$-tuples of elements in $k$ equipped with Zariski topology.

Edit 1 More assumption: $C\cap U\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Well, no. For instance, it's false for $C=\Bbb A^n_k\setminus U$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes you’re correct. I should put the assumption that $C\cap U$ nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your claim is true if we add some further hypotheses.

If $C$ is an **irreducible** Zariski-closed subset of $\mathbb A_k^n$ and $C \cap U$ is **non-empty**, then $\overline{C \cap U} = C$.

Indeed, suppose that this is false, i.e. $\overline{C \cap U} \subsetneq C$. Then $\overline{C \cap U}$ and $C \setminus U$ are two proper closed subsets of $C$ whose union is the whole of $C$. This contradicts the irreducibility of $C$.